# Why do webpages break in MVC if they're missing '/' from the URL?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I have a website that uses `cshtml` pages
  ie:  `index.cshtml` 
as a `View`  for my site

However if I browse in my URL to

`http://mywebsite.com/index`
 it breaks the rendering of the `_Layout`

but if I go to:

`http://mywebsite.com/index/`

It's magically working and using the correct `_Layout`